# Searching a column for a string in one array, and returning a value that corresponds to that array

Tags: excel

I am going to do my best to describe this.
I want to search column C for any of the strings contained on a different sheet in column A, and if/when one of those strings is found, i want to return the column B that corresponds to the found string.

For example:

Sheet 1:

| Column A | Column B | Column C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| project 1 | 2/15/19 | Status is Red, because.... |
| Project 2 | 4/12/20 | RAG- Green, PTG is.... |

And on another sheet I have common ways to describe their statuses in Column A, and in Column B, a simple letter R, A, G or NS (Not started) if no other common status is found.

| Column A | Column B | Column C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Status is Red | R |  |
| Rag- Green | G |  |

How can I Search Column C for a value on Column A (on a different sheet) and return column B in Column D on the original sheet?
Results should look like

| Column A | Column B | Column C | Column D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| project 1 | 2/15/19 | Status is Red, because.... | R |
| Project 2 | 4/12/20 | RAG- Green, PTG is.... | G |

Comment: `vlookup`? `index/match`?

Comment: Sounds like index() with match().

Answer (score 0):

This may be a bit of an extended function and depends on how many rows you have in the second sheet.

You can hard code it with

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Red",C2)),VLOOKUP("Status is Red",Sheet2!$A$2:$B$3,2,FALSE),IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Green",C2)),VLOOKUP("RAG - Green",Sheet2!$A$2:$B$3,2,FALSE),"NS"))
```

Or use the more dynamic:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(Sheet2!$A$2,Sheet1!C2)),VLOOKUP(Sheet2!$A$2,Sheet2!A2:B3,2,FALSE),IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(Sheet2!$A$3,Sheet1!C2)),VLOOKUP(Sheet2!$A$3,Sheet2!$A$2:$B$3,2,FALSE),"NS"))
```

## Explanation

- **SEARCH**(*find_text*,*within_text*) - returns the index of where the substring begins
- **ISNUMBER**(*value*) - returns TRUE if a number, FALSE if not.
- **VLOOKUP**(*lookup_value*,*table_array*,*col_index_num*,[*range_lookup*]) - finds the value within the array and returns the corresponding value in the specified column.
- $X$Y - the dollar signs stop the values from changing when you use ctrl+d or ctrl+r to fill multiple cells

So to break it down:

- IF (search returns an index)
- THEN VLOOKUP (find this value and return the corresponding value from this column)
- ELSE (repeat above as needed)
- ELSE ("NS")